# Fetch mySQL records which do not fall in list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following mySQL table:

```
ID  Name   Country  Industry

1   Abc    IN       Computer Software
2   Xyz    US       Banking
3   Mno    AU       Business Services
4   Pqr    FR       Media
```

And I have following two lists:

```
Country = [US, IN, NL, SA, SL],
Industry = [Computer Software, Computer Hardware, Construction, Business Services, Electronics]
```

I need a mySQL query to perform following task:

- Fetch records that does not match with list(Country OR Industry).
- e.g. : It should give me all data of records of **ID 2** as 'Banking' is not present in Industry, **ID 3** as 'AU' is not present in Country, **ID 4** as 'FR' is not present in Country & 'Media' is not present in Industry.

Comment: Try using "NOT EXISTS (SELECT...)"

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

Select * from table_name where Country not in ('US', 'IN', 'NL', 'SA', 'SL') OR Industry not in ('Computer Software', 'Computer Hardware','Construction', 'Business Services', 'Electronics')

Answer (score 0):

USE this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE 
Country NOT FIND_IN_SET(Country , 'US, IN, NL, SA, SL') 
OR NOT FIND_IN_SET(Industry, 'Computer Software, Computer Hardware, Construction, Business Services, Electronics')
```